# Display message when the cursor is over the NSSearchField

Tags: macos, cocoa, object, nssearchfield

I need to display a message similar the following attachmnet
[image: when cursor is over searchfield displays message like "Type a word or phrase ..."]

I dont know the technical term what exactly it called in cocoa terminology.
So,I could not google it also.just I am interested to know how can I implement this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called [tooltips](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OnlineHelp/Concepts/Tooltips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000469-BBCHADHH) and can be added to any view. You can add them programmatically like so:

```
[searchField setToolTip:@"Hello World!"];
```